# File list resolver for grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm using `grunt-contrib-uglify` to build my [asmcrypto.js](https://github.com/vibornoff/asmcrypto.js) project. It's properly structured and split into individual components residing each at own folder.

Now I'd like to give a user an option to select wich components to include into resulting minified file. Components may have dependancies to other components and they should be resolved automatically.

I suppose the final solution should be something like `grunt with:aes-cbc with:hmac-sha256` implying that dependancies are built in too.

From my point of view it should be a grunt plugin able to traverse dependancy tree and return combined source file list which can be passed to `grunt-contrib-uglify`.

Have a couple of hours trying:

- `grunt-feature`
- `grunt-component-build`
- `grunt-resolve`

None can do what I described or I didn't find a proper way from docs.

Comment: Are you trying to build the grunt configuration dynamically?

Comment: Seems like. I'm wonder it's so non-trivial since `make` has been invented 37 years ago. Can't believe I'm first who need dependancy resolving for building JS project.